# SQL: conditioning in aggregation function

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I have following sql:

```
  SELECT LISTAGG((TO_CHAR(ch.count), '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ch.Count)
    FROM ChG cg
    JOIN Ch ch on ch.GroupID = cg.GroupID
    WHERE cg.PartyID = cp.PartyID
```

I would like to add condition, pseudocode: 
`if(ch.TYPECODE = 1) then ch.count = 'A' + ch.count`. How it's better to achieve in stored procedure?

Comment: What do you mean by `'A' + ch.count`? Do you mean concatenate? Oracle uses `||` for that, not the plus sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listagg(case when ch.typecode = 1 then 'A' end || to_char(ch.count), '|') .....
```

Before aggregation, each row is inspected for the condition `ch.typecode = 1`. If it is true, an `'A'` is pre-pended (concatenated in front of) `to_char(ch.count)`. I am just guessing that's what you need.

If you need this `'A'` to be pre-pended to `ch.count` for the ORDER BY condition also, then you can do the same thing there. You will need to wrap within `to_char` as well. (If you don't, Big Brother Oracle will do it for you anyway, but try to avoid implicit conversions whenever possible.)